# Xtext PDE give exception after start up

Tags: eclipse, xtext, eclipse-pde

My text ui project give an exception after the plug in is started. The scoping class is implemented. There are only two txt files ion xtext project when running the PDE

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui 2 0 2016-10-11 21:53:35.798
!MESSAGE java.lang.NullPointerException
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.SetupUIPlugin.performStartup(SetupUIPlugin.java:373)
at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.SetupUIPlugin.access$4(SetupUIPlugin.java:344)
at   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.SetupUIPlugin$1$1.run(SetupUIPlugin.java:241)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

How can I track down the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the exception trace, the error is caused by the [Oomph installer](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.oomph) trying to execute some startup tasks, and thus unrelated to your plug-in being developed or Xtext.

In order to solve the issue, I have two ideas:

1. Turn off all Oomph-related plug-ins in your run configuration, and thus these tasks will not start. Look for the Plug-ins tab of the run configuration of your job to do that.
2. In runtime Eclipse instances the plug-in installation is turned off by default, while Oomph might want to install something. You could try to enable it in your run configuration on the configuration tab (see screenshot below).

[image: Enabling software installation in runtime Eclipse instances]